# Android tablet nexus 10 got exception on widget 'cannot fit on this device'

Tags: android, widget

everyone

I got a exception on tablet nexus 10, the widget was not shown in the widget list. The exception looks like:

10-11 16:53:20.185 E/AppsCustomizePagedView(2811): Widget ComponentInfo{com.allocine.androidapp/com.allocine.androidapp.providers.WidgetAlloCineProvider} can not fit on this device (1400, 1200)

It will be apprectiated if anyone could offer help.

Thanks.

Ping

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is because of the minimum width and height size that you have define for your widget in widget info xml is too much for this device.

Try reducing the min_height and min_width and you should be able to see your widget in the list.